# Abstract object or creating a class-like object

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the confusing title, I don't really know how to name what I want to do.
I currently have this code:

```
const utils = (function () {

  const tabsWithAudio = {
    tabsArray: [],
    add: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index < 0) {
        this.tabsArray.push(tabId);
      }
    },
    remove: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.tabsArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    contains: function (tabId) {
      return (this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId) > -1);
    },
  };


  const tabsWithWidget = {
    tabsArray: [],
    add: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index < 0) {
        this.tabsArray.push(tabId);
      }
    },
    remove: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.tabsArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    contains: function (tabId) {
      return (this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId) > -1);
    },
  };

  return {
    tabsWithAudio: tabsWithAudio,
    tabsWithWidget: tabsWithWidget,
  };
}());

module.exports = utils;
```

Then I use them like this:

```
const utils = require('./modules/utils');

...


utils.tabsWithAudio.add(123);

....
```

But since all thos objects are the same, I want to create a class-like object that I can instantiate on the go, eg.:

```
let tabsWithAudio = new utils.tabsHelper();
utils.tabsWithAudio.add(123);
```

I tried this, but everything inside the prototype didn't get exported I guess:

```
const utils = (function () {

  const tabsHelper = function() {};
  tabsHelper.prototype = {
    tabsArray: [],
    add: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index < 0) {
        this.tabsArray.push(tabId);
      }
    },
    remove: function (tabId) {
      const index = this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.tabsArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    contains: function (tabId) {
      return (this.tabsArray.indexOf(tabId) > -1);
    },
  };



  return {
    tabsHelper: tabsHelper,
  };
}());

module.exports = utils;
```

Any idea what am I missing? Also, what is this called btw.

THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Cornwell I read your question and my answer wont be any 'code.'  You clearly know your stuff and I believe you are just looking for some clarification.

You are correct in knowing that these code snippets are not 'classes.'  At least in the classical sense.  What you are referring to are 'modules.' More specifically, you are using an IIFE (to create closure) and then returning an object that has references to functions within that IIFE.  This is a module which uses closure.

More info on this pattern can be found [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html).  One thing to note.  When using the 'frame' of 'classes.' Modules are not instantiated they are returned.

JavaScript classes ARE instantiated but the pattern looks different.  Here is a resource to [pseudoclassical instantiation patterns.](http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern)  Here is a link to [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which are generally where the language is heading.  One more [link.](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/) The keyword "new" is only associated with instantiation.  Instantiation is associated with classes.